# Binding enum to form <select> element in Play! Framework 2.1

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to figure out best practice to bind `enum` to form drop-down `<select>` in Play! 2.0

Here is my enum:

```
public enum ContactType {
    CLIENT(1),
    CONTRACTOR(2),
    SUPPLIER(3);

    public final int id;

    ContactType(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And here's what i'd like to get as result in my view:

```
<select name="contactType">
  <option value="1">CLIENT</option>
  <option value="2">CONTRACTOR</option>
  <option value="3">SUPPLIER</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this in your template should work:

```
<select name="contactType">
    @for(cType <- ContactType.values()){
        <option value="@cType.id">@cType.name()</option>
    }
</select>
```

*Note:* it may be better to use `toString()` instead of `name()`. If you override `toString()` in your enum you could return Contractor instead of CONTRACTOR.

*Note 2:* if your enum is not in the `models` package you need to prefix it with the right package name i.e.: `@for(cType <- com.my_company.enums.ContactType)`

Comment: @ainla You're welcome. I manually added your edits as they got rejected, although I believe it's important to distinguish between `type` (reserved) and `cType`, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @ainla, guys how can we make a view which would work for any enum type?

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you are putting the select into a HTML form, the way it is done in our shop is we add a Map to the Java enum and then use the select form helper provided by the framework:

enum:

```
public enum ContactType {
    CLIENT(1),
    CONTRACTOR(2),
    SUPPLIER(3);

    public final int id;

    ContactType(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> options(){
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> vals = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (ContactTypecType cType: ContactType.values()) {
            vals.put(cType.id(), cType.name());
        }
        return vals;
    }
}
```

view:

```
@(contactForm: Form[models.Contact])

import helper._

<html><head></head><body>
@helper.form(routes.Contact.formHandlerMethod()){
    @* 
     * Here contactForm("contactType") assumes that you want to map the 
     * ContactType selected to a field in a Contact class (which we've 
     * wrapped in play.data.Form<T> so that the fields in Contact become 
     * inputs in our form
     *@
    @select(contactForm("contactType"), options(ContactType.options())
}
</body></html>
```

Using this design pattern you can leverage the helper functions in the play.data.Form class to validate and bind your form data in your Contact Controller and you benefit from having less logic in your view, and putting the logic in a place where it can easily be re-used throughout your app.

If, on the other hand, you are using the select on it's own and driving actions in some other way, then Aerus' answer is probably the most straightforward way.

Comment: Thanks! This is also a very elegant solution. Keeps the view code nice and clean.

Comment: Nice solution, but you are missing static modifier: public static Map<String, String> options()

Comment: Good catch, @cosmolev.  I don't have the rep to approve your edit, but I'll edit it myself.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** The form should not include all the classpath to the enum, just the enum name. So on the ContactType class, the put method has to be replaced to this:

```
            put(value.name(),name);
```

---

I'm not able to bind the enum to the class. In the controller I have something like that:

```
public Result saveUser() {
    Form<User> userForm = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(userForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(createUser.render(userForm));
    }
    User user=userForm.get();
    user.save();
    Logger.info(user.contacts.toString());
    flash("success", "User " + userForm.get().identity + " has been created");
    return GO_ADMIN;
}
```

Which is returning me all the time "error.invalid".
The POST response looks like that:

```
identity=asas&
status=1&
contacts[0].name=fasddf&
contacts[0].prename=afadfs&
contacts[0].email=ffdf@aa.com&
contacts[0].contactType=models.constats.ContactType.MANAGER
```

Just to have more information, I provide here the User and the Contact classes

**User**

```
public class User extends Model{
    @Constraints.Required(message = "Field is required")
    public String identity;
    public Integer status;
    @Valid
    public List<Contact> contacts; 
}
```

**Contact**

```
public class Contact extends Generic{

    @Constraints.Required(message = "Field is required")
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required(message = "Field is required")
    public String prename;

    @Constraints.Required(message = "Field is required")
    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;

    public ContactType contactType; 
}
```

**ContactType**

```
public enum ContactType {

    ADMIN,SUPPORT,MANAGER,DEVELOPER,DESIGNER,NO_INFORMATION;
}
    public static final Map<String,Object> types=new HashMap<String,Object>()
    {{
        for (ContactType value : ContactType.values()) {
            String name=value.name().toLowerCase();
            name=Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1).replaceAll("_", " ");
            put(ContactType.class.getName() + "."+ value.name(),name);
        }
    }};
```

Comment: I answer myself and I share my conclussions in case somobody have the same problem: by default, bind using the **enum name**. My post method was wrong, since it was sending the full path to the enum "models.constants.ContactType.SUPPORT". The correct is to send only **SUPPORT** in this case.

Comment: Hi great answer! My only problem is that when I pass a prefilled form in, it doesn't seem to have any radio button checked. Did you face the same problem?

Comment: That depends on how you are implementing the radio button behavior at the view. In my case, I'm no using the helpers provided by Play because I am using Bootstrap for the view, so for the checking part I use the code `@if(field.value.getOrElse("").equals("true")){checked}`

Comment: I am not using the helper either, I used the code from the helper and updated it to my own since I am using bootstrap as well, but I simply could not get that to work. Would you mind sharing the radio button code?

Comment: this is what I have - `@if(value == Some(v._1)){checked="checked"}` where v is a pair from the Map that is returned.

Comment: I figured it out... I was overriding toString() to return the human readable value and it seems that the form's binding uses toString() to bind the values.